Showing $\frac{e^{i\pi/3} - 1}{e^{i\pi/3} + 1} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$
Is there a good way to see this?
$$\frac{e^{i\pi/3} - 1}{e^{i\pi/3} + 1} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$$
What I can do is to write
$$e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}} - 1 = \cos\frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin\frac{\pi}{3} - 1 = -\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$
$$e^{\frac{\pi}{3}} + 1 = \frac{3}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
So the second term is some complex number $re^{i\theta}$ with $r = \sqrt{\frac{9}{4} + \frac{3}{4}} = \sqrt{3}$ and $\theta = \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}) = \frac{\pi}{6}$. Once we plug this into the expression we get the answer.
I had to use Wolfram Alpha to compute $\theta = \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}) $ and I wonder if there is a trick here that simplifies the calculation and does not require a calculator.

Hint: multiply and divide by $\frac{3}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\frac32+i\frac{\sqrt3}2=\sqrt3\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\right)=\sqrt3e^{i\frac\pi6}$

An equivalent way to put the previous comments is to multiply and divide by $e^{-i\pi/6}$.

In general, since $$\dfrac{a-1}{a+1} = 1 - \dfrac{2}{a+1} ,$$ we have $$\dfrac{a-1}{a+1} =  b \ \Longleftrightarrow \ 1 - \dfrac{2}{a+1} = b \ \Longleftrightarrow \ a+1 = \dfrac{2}{1-b} \ \Longleftrightarrow \ a = \dfrac{2}{1-b} - 1 = \dfrac{1+b}{1-b} .$$ Therefore, what we have to prove is just $$e^{i\pi/3} = \dfrac{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}i}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}i} .$$ Do you have any ideas how?

Defining $s:=\sin t$ and $c:=\cos t$ for brevity, we have in general:
$$\frac{e^{2it}-1}{e^{2it}+1}=\frac{-1+\cos2t+i\sin2t}{\phantom{-}1+\cos2t+i\sin2t}=\frac{-2s^2+2isc}{\phantom{-}2c^2+2isc}=\frac{s}{c}\cdot\frac{ic-s}{c+is}=\frac{s}{c}\cdot i=i\tan t$$ In your case, $t=\pi/6$.

$$
\frac{e^{i\pi/3}-1}{e^{i\pi/3}+1}=\frac{e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}}{\sqrt3e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{6})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
Is not that enough?

Algebraically, we can write
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\exp2i\theta-1}{\exp2i\theta+1} 
&=\frac{-1+\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta}{\phantom{-}1+\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta} \\[4pt]
&=\frac{-2\sin^2\theta+2i\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\phantom{-}2\cos^2\theta+2i\sin\theta\cos\theta} \\[4pt]
&=\frac{i\cos\theta-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}\cdot\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} \\[4pt]
&= i\,\tan\theta
\end{align}$$
In OP's specific case, we have $\theta=\pi/6$.

Geometrically, if $z:=\exp2i\theta=\operatorname{cis}2\theta$, and $z_+:=z+1$ and $z_-:=z-1$, we generally have (for a restricted range of $\theta$) this configuration, featuring a right triangle:

Since $\angle z_+Oz_- = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and $\dfrac{|z_-|}{|z_+|}=\tan\theta$, we have $$\frac{z_-}{z_+} = i\tan\theta$$
which makes the diagram a pretty nice way to see the identity.

Thank you very much for such a detailed answer!
